# Python split string exactly on one space. if double space make " word" not "word"

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have the following string.

`words = "this is a  book and i  like it"`

What i want is that when i split it by one space i get the following.

`wordList = words.split(" ")
print wordList 
<< ['this','is','a',' book','and','i',' like','it']`

Simple `words.split(" ")` function splits the string but incase of double space it remove both spaces which gives `'book'` and `'like'`. and what i need is `' book'` and `' like'` keeping extra spaces intact in the split output in case of double, triple... n spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another regex solution: if you need to split with a single left-most whitespace char, use `\s?` to match one or zero whitespaces, and then *capture* 0+ remaining whitespaces and the subsequent non-whitespace chars.

***One very important step*: run `rstrip` on the input string before running the regex to remove all the trailing whitespace, since otherwise, its performance will decrease greatly.**

```
import re
words = "this is a  book and i  like it"
print(re.findall(r'\s?(\s*\S+)', words.rstrip()))
# => ['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hlpICm). The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns just the captured substrings and since we only have one capturing group, the result is a list of those captures.

Also, here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HOJrE/1). Details:

- `\s?` - 1 or 0 (due to `?` quantifier) whitespaces
- `(\s*\S+)`  - Capturing group #1 matching

  - `\s*` - zero or more (due to the `*` quantifier) whitespace
  - `\S+` - 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier) non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: Very well explained, Thanks mate!

Comment: @QaisarRajput: Could you please explain why it turned out working best for you? Psidom's solution looks to be designed for your exact requirements (i.e. splitting) and was posted before my answer.

Comment: both of the solutions worked and i upvoted both the answers and thanked both of you guys. i selected yours because it was explained a bit more so that if someone new is looking for the same solution would know what is what.

Answer (score 5):

You can split on whitespace that is not preceded by white space using *look behind* (?<=) syntax:

```
import re

re.split("(?<=\\S) ", words)
# ['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it']
```

Or similarly, use negative look behind:

```
re.split("(?<!\\s) ", words)
# ['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it']
```

Comment: No, not equivalently. `"(?<=\\S) "` is not the full equivalent of `"(?<!\\s) "`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What's the difference?

Comment: The first one requires a non-space character to be there. Thus, it won't work if a string starts with a space.

Comment: If it were only about *this specific problem*, you could do `print(['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it'])`. ;-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Got you. I was thinking too fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like using a regex and want to keep something close to your own code, you could use something like this:

```
words = "this is a  book and i  like it"
wordList = words.split(" ")
for i in range(len(wordList)):
    if(wordList[i]==''):
        wordList[i+1] = ' ' + wordList[i+1]
wordList = [x for x in wordList if x != '']  
print wordList
# Outputs: ['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using a list comprehension:

```
word_list = iter(words.split(" "))
["".join([" ", next(word_list)]) if not w else w for w in word_list] 
# ['this', 'is', 'a', ' book', 'and', 'i', ' like', 'it']
```